# On gh-pages css isn't applying, despite common fixes

Tags: html, css, github-pages

I'm having an issue with my GitHub pages site, where the CSS isn't being applied to the HTML despite trying common fixes. The live version of the site can be found at CleantheCapital.com, and the GitHub repository can be found at https://github.com/BrianStiner/CleantheCapital.

The HTML code is all correct, but the CSS file is not being loaded. The link to the CSS file is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
```

https://github.com/BrianStiner/CleantheCapital/blob/gh-pages/style.css

And the "style.css" file is in the same folder as the "index.html" file. However, when I load the site, the HTML is not being styled by the CSS.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

I have tried the following common fixes without success:

Clearing browser cache

Ensuring that the file names and paths are correct

Not sure what to do after that

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try adding `./`?  Try changing the attribute to `href="./style.css"`.